# Composite Id in Jquery DataTable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatable, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using a DataTable, I need to do a link for accessing a row. But the row has a composite Key

The key is composed by IdEnvironment(int) and a Limit (decimal)

Here is my model:

```
public partial class ApprovalHierarchy
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Ambiente")]
    [DataTables(DisplayName = "Ambiente", MRenderFunction = "encloseInEmTag",Order =1)]
    public int IdEnvironment { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Límite de aprobación")]
    [DataTables(DisplayName = "Límite de aprobación", MRenderFunction = "encloseInEmTag",Order =1)]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]+([.][0-9]{1,2})?$", ErrorMessage = "El límite debe de ser un número con dos decimales")]
    public decimal Limit { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Descripción")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Moneda")]
    public Nullable<int> IdCurrency { get; set; }

    public virtual Environment Environment { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers { get; set; }

    public virtual Currency Currency { get; set; }
}
```

}

When I put the DataTable Annotation `MRenderFunction = "encolseInEmTag"
the Id of the link changes but I need to send it as a composite key in parameters for access  to this method in my controller:

```
    // GET: /ApprovalHierarchy/Details/5
    public ActionResult ModalDetails(int? id,decimal? limit)
    {
        if (id == null || limit ==null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        ApprovalHierarchy approvalHierarchy = db.ApprovalHierarchy.First(x => x.IdEnvironment==
        id && x.Limit == limit);
        if (approvalHierarchy == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return PartialView("Details",approvalHierarchy);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that creating a new attribute in my model and setting the value in my controller.

Model Attribute:

```
[Key,DataTables(MRenderFunction = "encloseInEmTag",Visible =false)]
public string CompositeId { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
 row.CompositeId = query.ElementAt(i).IdEnvironment + "?Limit=" + query.ElementAt(i).Limit.ToString().Replace(",",".");
```